# Is it possible to add a custom button in Sharepoint 2010 Ribbon just for a specific page?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon, custom-action

Is it possible to add a custom button in Sharepoint 2010 Ribbon just for a specific page?

I found many examples about adding a custom button in Sharepoint 2010 Ribbon via CustomActions (XML) in Visual Studio 2010, but nothing about adding it in a specific page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this not possible via custom actions.

However, you could write a delegate control that creates your ribbon button through code.

[SharePoint 2010 Fluent Ribbon API](http://spribbon.codeplex.com/) helps you creating ribbon elements programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

To see how you can do what Stefan suggests, you can take a look at Part 2 of  my [blog post series here](http://www.cagataykalan.com/blog/custom-button-in-sharepoint-2010-ribbon-publishing-tab-part-1/). In the same way, you can check the current page in your server side code so that you can show/hide a ribbon button.